# Angular project can't be Build?

Tags: angular, jenkins, bootstrap-5

I migrated my current project from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5 and since then jenkins can't build the project anymore.
I just get the cryptic message :

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot destructure property 'bold' of 'core_1.terminal' as it is undefined.
```

We searched for that error and couldn't find the meaning of this!
I can build the project on my local machine without any problems but jenkins just don't like to build it.

I just changed HTML and SCSS files nothing else!

Comment: Are you cleaning the workspace in the Jenkins pipeline before building it. It could be the bad node_modules that is causing this

Answer (score 0):

If you ever worked with `@angular-devkit` package specially if you work with Ionic framework  you might have noticed following error at least once

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot destructure property 'bold' of 'core_1.terminal' as it is undefined.
```

to solve this error you can run following commands in your terminal (administrator access is recommended)

```
npm -g install chalk

npm -g install @angular-devkit/core
```

**In some cases** it might not solve your problem than you can try to remove angular from your system and reinstall it globally. (use commands below)

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli
```

[Source](https://irando.co.id/articles/how-to-solve-cannot-destructure-property-bold-in-npm)

Comment: The link might go down, it'd be better if you can copy the relevant sections here.